# How to change the background of selected link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using `<ul><li></li></ul>` 
I want to change the background of the selected `<li>` or page. 
Please guide me which solution is best for this and please also provide any helping material.

Thanks.

Comment: `<li>` creates a list, not a link. Also, tell us more. You want to change the background color/image of a list when it is clicked on? Is that what you mean by selected?

Comment: @Amaan `<li>` creates a list item, no a list.

Comment: @Gumbo Thanks. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this trick

`#menuspace li.active a {
    background:#fff;
    color:#2175bc;`

or see the live example :- 
http://jsfiddle.net/3XzVF/2/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need something like this

```
    $('li').click(function(){

       $(this).css({'background-color':'red'});
    });
```

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to use javascript here.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to add background to active li you should add :active to li.
**The :active selector is used to select and style the active link.**

```
li:active{
  background:#fff;
}
```

define this in your stylesheet
you can change :active to :hover

heres the tutorial you may need
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

P.S. You always should check stack archive or google your question first as this question is very common.

Answer (score 0):

### Activation

If you want to change the style of the list item when it is activated, use the pseudo-class `:active`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/srGGc/

Note that activation is not the same as selection.

> The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated
>   by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse
>   button and releases it. On systems with more than one mouse button,
>   :active applies only to the primary or primary activation button
>   (typically the "left" mouse button), and any aliases thereof.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#active-pseudo

### Selection

If you want to mark the list item as selected when you are on its corresponding page, you can do that client-side with JavaScript that checks the URL and sets the class name on the `LI`.

```
if( window.location.href.lastIndexOf("jshell.net") != -1 )
{
    document.getElementById("foo").className = "activeItem";
}​
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/j4DXb/1/

You can also set a class name server-side (this is usually my preferred method).